# How to enable ssh on extreme summit x450e-24p and x450e-48p switch?

Tags: router, switch

How do you enable ssh on  extreme summit x450e-48p and  x450e-48p switch for secure login. Do I need to purchase a license for that? I haven't found any commands on switch cli.

Comment: Can I suggest that if you don't know how to switch it on or where to look to find out that perhaps you should reconsider whether to do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

I searched Google with this query:

https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+on+extreme+summit+x450e-48

The first entry is a blurb about the switch, and it lists this in its Technical Specifications section:

> Secure Shell (SSH-2), Secure Copy (SCP-2) and SFTP client/server with
>   encryption/ authentication (requires export controlled encryption
>   module)

Do you have the encryption module?

You could have found this yourself - you *should* know how. If you don't, then *learn*: it is critical that you know how to find answers yourself first before asking others.

Comment: Ok i'll do that myself

Answer (score 0):

Extreme package SSH as a separate module, as such, the core image has absolutely no SSH capabilities whatsoever.

You need to obtain the SSH xmod, install it in the same way you would for a full image (`download image`) and then do `run update` to make it usable.